# Javascript + Regex = Breaks function call somehow

Tags: javascript, html, regex

html code:

```
<div class="submitForm">
  <input type="button" value="button" onclick="doValidateForm();" /></div>
```

javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function doValidateForm() {
    if (!/^[0-9]+${5}/.test(zip) && zip != "") {
      alert("Zip has invalid characters.");
      return false;
    }
  }
</script>
```

The problem is the {5}.  With it in I get "JavaScript runtime error: 'doValidateForm' is undefined."  I've moved the {5} around in the expression.  With it not there, the code executes fine.

I've tried:

```
/^[0-9]{5}+$/.test(zip)
```

and

```
/^{5}[0-9]+$/.test(zip)
```

But it still breaks.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

*edit* fixed code.

Comment: You can find a tutorial about regex here: http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Comment: lol zzzz.  And thanks Casimir.

Comment: So how are you planning on handling zipcodes with the 4 digit extension (e.x. 12345-6789)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This condition:

```
if (!/^[0-9]+${5}/.test(zip) && zip != "")
```

should be rewritten as:

```
if (/^\d{5}$/.test(zip) == false) {
```

Answer (score 1):

You are probably looking for this regex:

```
/^[0-9]{5}$/
```

It matches 5-digit numbers (with leading zeroes counting as digits)

Use it like this:

```
if (!/^[0-9]{5}$/.test(zip)) { ...
```

Quick explanation:

`+` means "once or more"
`{5}` means "exactly 5 times"

So is doesn't make sense to have `+` and `{5}` one after the other in any regex. It's kinda like asking javascript to calculate what `3+*5` is. It's just a rough comparison - the similarity lies in operators being used without operands)